# Wired keyboard intermittent

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have an Acer desktop that has an intermittent USB keyboard. I tried replacing it with another older keyboard and still experienced the problem. I even purchased a new Microsoft keyboard but the problem still exists. I also tried switching ports and reinstalling drivers. As I type sometimes only every third letter doesn't appear. Sometimes the computer makes a sound when the letters don't type. The computer is about 3 yrs old but the problem just started happening less than 30 days ago (Windows 8)

Comment: We need more information and troubleshooting on your end (and an actual question) to be able to give you an actual answer.  For one, you need to rule out software - Does it behave the same way in Safe Mode? If you boot to another OS (like say, a Linux LiveCD) does it still have the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Whjat have you tried so far to fix it?

Have you tried a system restore?  If not, try rolling back your PC to just before you started having problems and see if the issue persists.

Try updating your BIOS, chipset and USB drivers.  It is possible that these have been partly corrupted.  I know you day you have tried the USB driver install, but have you tried the others?  This will rule out all affected drivers.

Have you done a full AV/malware/spyware scan??? there is a lot fo stuff out there on the net that likes to mess with you like this.  This will rule out viruses etc.

Do the devices work in another machine?  Of course, this assumes you have access to another machine!  Thsi will rule out you being very unlucky and buying a dodgy keyboard after your last one broke

Could it be a port problem?? do you have multiple USB cards (for instance both onboard motherboard AND a PCI card?)  Try swapping from one set to another... alternatively, try other types of hardware in that port (mouse, printer) and see if they misbehave - this will allow you to ule out a dodgy port.

Comment: indeed what he desribed is probably the USB port (or hub) itself dropping out, it could probably be seen in the device manager. There are many occurances of that happening to people in SU questions. I would love to know the actual cause, and what actually solves it more permentently. Maybe some power save thing going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you have intermittent drops it is a power based issue. the standard power output for a USB port is 5W, however on many computers this is 5W per BUS not USB.

For example, my turtlebeach headphones stop over ports on the same bus from powering.

What other devices do you have plugged in via USB.